# Monotouch: Unregister a licence

Tags: xamarin.ios, license-key

We restored a computer with Time Machine which had an active MonoTouch licence.

We need to remove the Monotouch license and just use the box as a coding box, not a builder.

Is this possible/allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install that license on another machine without deactivating the previous one as I believe [you can activate it twice](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/177037-can-i-use-my-license-on-more-than-one-machine-) before you have to remove the license. To remove ours, I emailed the team at monotouch directly through the website [contact form here.](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/emails/new)

I've found the Monotouch email support to be **VERY** helpful. They're prompt and more than happy to accomodate any problems you have - so I'd suggest emailing them if you have any problems.

**EDIT - 9th Dec 2012**
Update based on [Kirk Woll's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189950/kirk-woll) comment:
today you can only activate a given key one time before you must deactivate it on xamarin.com. However, deactivating is simply a matter of logging in, selecting your license, and "recycling your workstation". (And you can recycle a workstation at most 2 times a year).

Comment: This answer is probably just old, but today you can only activate a given key *one* time before you *must* deactivate it on xamarin.com.  However, deactivating is simply a matter of logging in, selecting your license, and "recycling your workstation".  (And you can recycle a workstation at most 2 times a year)